# How do I SELECT a SUM of multiple GROUP BY rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relationship table of players to matches and the points they've scored in each. I'm trying to do a SELECT in which I get a distinct list of players with their total points scored as well as the total points scored by all teams that they've been on. Since everything is in terms of single players, I don't know how to get out of the GROUP BY scope for only that single column. For the examples below, I'll just say that each team only has two players. In the actual database, each team has five if it matters. Thanks guys.

**Table "matches":**

```
match_id | winning_team |

56427859 |            0 |
56427860 |            1 |
56427861 |            1 |
56427862 |            0 |
56427863 |            1 |

etc...
```

**Table "match_players":**

```
match_id | team | player_id | points |

56427859 |    0 |        10 |      3 |
56427859 |    0 |        33 |      1 |
56427859 |    1 |        26 |      0 |
56427859 |    1 |        39 |      2 |
56427860 |    0 |        23 |      1 |
56427860 |    0 |        33 |      3 |
56427860 |    1 |        18 |      1 |
56427860 |    1 |        10 |      4 |

etc...
```

**Desired result:**

```
player_id | match_count | total_points | team_total_points | <- This should be
                                                                the total of all
       10 |           2 |            7 |                 9 |    points scored by
       18 |           1 |            1 |                 5 |    the player and
       23 |           1 |            1 |                 4 |    his teammates
       26 |           1 |            0 |                 2 |    in all matches.
       33 |           2 |            4 |                 8 |
       39 |           1 |            2 |                 2 |
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT
    p.player_id,
    COUNT(*) AS match_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mp.team = m.winning_team THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS win_count,
    SUM(points) AS total_points,
    [________________________________________] AS team_total_points
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN match_players mp ON m.match_id = mp.match_id
INNER JOIN players p ON mp.player_id = p.player_id
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY player_id
```

**Edit:**

The "team" column simply defines red or blue, home or away, etc. Players can be on different teams in different matches. And players can swap teams between matches, like recess dodgeball.

Comment: How do you define a "team"?

Comment: Right, sorry. There are only two. Team just means home and away, basically. Players can be on any team at any time. Like dodgeball. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Write a subquery that calculates the team total for each player. Join that subquery with your main query, and put the total into the blank.

Comment: I tried something similar and I couldn't capture teammates' points for some reason. Won't any "(SELECT SUM(points)..." of any sort inside the brackets just return a sum of each particular player's points and none of the others' due to the group by? Sorry for my poor SQL understanding.

Comment: @Barmar - Oh, you mean like Vitto is showing in his post. Ok, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Thx @Barmar. Sometimes i see the answer right after reading my own question :-) - i thought there is score per team and game. Didn't see players can have different score in same team for a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will calculate the total points for all players on the same team as each player.

```
SELECT p1.player_id, SUM(p2.total_points) AS team_total_points
FROM match_players AS p1
JOIN (SELECT match_id, team, SUM(points) as total_points
      FROM match_players
      GROUP BY match_id, team) AS p2
ON p1.match_id = p2.match_id AND p1.team = p2.team
GROUP BY p1.player_id
```

You can then join that with the original query to add the team totals.

```
SELECT
    p.player_id,
    COUNT(*) AS match_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mp.team = m.winning_team THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS win_count,
    SUM(points) AS total_points,
    mp2.team_total_points
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN match_players mp ON m.match_id = mp.match_id
INNER JOIN players p ON mp.player_id = p.player_id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT p1.player_id, SUM(p2.total_points) AS team_total_points
     FROM match_players AS p1
     JOIN (SELECT match_id, team, SUM(points) as total_points
           FROM match_players
           GROUP BY match_id, team) AS p2
     ON p1.match_id = p2.match_id AND p1.team = p2.team
     GROUP BY p1.player_id) AS mp2 ON mp2.player_id = p.player_id
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY player_id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4e079/1)

Comment: I can't believe I got this right on the first try :)

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Yeah, I was in the process of writing something similar just now. The problem before was that I didn't realize you can join with the results of a SELECT statement. That's awesome. Thanks man.

Comment: It seems like I can even just pull the total_points out of the JOIN and use it in the main query rather that recalculate them with another SUM, right? Although MySQL would optimize that out anyway?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible that this can be simplified a bit, but I think (hope) MySQL will optimize it to the same thing. This is what I get from building up modularly.

Comment: And I just thought about it... You wrote all the code to create the tables for the demo too. And got a working query in under 12 mins from the time you made the suggestion. You're a speed demon. Lol.

Comment: The table stuff was automated by sqlfiddle, I just pasted your tables into the Text to DDL dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT player_id, COUNT(*) AS match_count, SUM(points) AS total_points, team_tot_points
FROM match_players JOIN (SELECT SUM(points) AS team_tot_points, team
                         FROM match_players
                         GROUP BY team) AS team_points
ON match_players.team = team_points.team
GROUP BY player_id
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, because sometimes a player is on team 0, and sometimes they're on team 1, depending on whether it's a home or away game.

Comment: @ Barmar - True, but I can figure that part out. I'll try this. Thanks Vitto.

Comment: @DaiBu See my answer.

Comment: So how do you define players which are in the same team? Are they the ones which have the same team in the same match?

Comment: @Vitto Yes, that's how it works. You can be on the home team in match 1, but the away team in match 2.